# "Tomorrow and the day after"

Tags: word-usage

I know there's a fixed phrase *the day after tomorrow*. But is it possible to omit the second *tomorrow* in the following sentence?

> We won't be meeting tomorrow and the day after [tomorrow].

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely fine to omit "tomorrow" in normal parlance.

Comment: You could also say "We won't be meeting tomorrow or the next day."

Comment: The fixed phrase is **not** "the day after tomorrow" – it's simply "the day after". It can be _the day after [any day reference]_. Hence: "We won't be open on Christmas or the day after" (means we will be closed Dec 25 and Dec 26); or, "Aunt Lois will leave on Monday or the day after" (means she's planning to leave on Monday or Tuesday).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the second *tomorrow*, but you've got the wrong conjunction in your sentence. It should read:

> We won't be meeting tomorrow ***or*** the day after.

By using tomorrow previously in the sentence, you've already implied it as the word after *after*. So that should be just fine.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why is the conjunction _or_ correct but not _and_? Also, wouldn't _or_ give rise to ambiguity here? The other interpretation seems to show that only one of the two choices (tomorrow or the day after) can be true, and that the speaker isn't sure which of them exactly.

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where English and Logic actually match up!  Not(A) and Not(B) == Not(A or B).  If you don't repeat the not, you have to change the conjunction to keep the logic valid.

Comment: @Sherlock What Hellion said :) You can say "We will not be meeting tomorrow and we will not be meeting the day after tomorrow" or you can say "We will not be meeting tomorrow or the day after."

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly acceptable as the day after refers is said relative to tomorrow. If you're feeling a bit old-fashioned, you can use [overmorrow](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Overmorrow) to say the same thing:

> We won't be meeting tomorrow and overmorrow.

Note that, while correct, *overmorrow* is not at all commonly used anyone, and even native speakers might not know what you mean.

Comment: In that case, he could also say _to-morrow_. `:)`

Comment: You're right, _overmorrow_ isn't used. In fact, it's not even included in [many](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english/overmorrow) [dictionaries](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=overmorrow). I would strongly recommend **not** using it, unless you wanted to deliberately sound oddly out-of-date.

Answer (score -1):

Overmorrow, it means the day after tomorrow

Comment: Welcome to ELL SE! Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question at hand; it merely offers an alternative, which I never heard of. Do you have a dictionary reference to support you?

Comment: I think that one's been pushing up the daisies for a long time. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45412/how-obsolete-is-the-word-overmorrow

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13227/the-night-before-last-night/13232#13232

Comment: Yes, it's been [_pushing up daisies,_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pushing_up_daisies) but no _definite_ ones, for a century. The answer might still be interesting if @IrwellPete were motivated to expand it by adding references, as suggested, and perhaps by pointing out that English seems to be the only Germanic language which lacks an "accepted" word for _the day after tomorrow._ The history, including the puzzling and seemingly intentional exile of the word, is fascinating.

Comment: @P.E.DantReinstateMonica As this old answer has been recently flagged, I am ready to delete it. But I do wonder if _you_ would like to elaborate on what you hinted at in the comment and expand it into an answer? I'd be very glad to add a bounty to your answer to highlight it.