# The night before last night?

Tags: adverbs, time

I could say *"I am leaving the day after tomorrow,"* but what if I want to reference the night before last night? Do I say, *"I left the night before last night"*? What do native speakers say both formally and **informally** in particular?
I researched the question but could not find a clear definite answer, and I do not want to speculate.

Comment: note in many languages there are specific words for "day after tomorrow" or "day before yesterday", but not in English - don't seek them in vain.

Comment: You can also say: two nights  ago. Or 3/4/... nights ago.

Answer (score 13):

The phrase *the night before last night* is exactly how I'd reference it, although, in many contexts – and that includes informal contexts – I'd typically leave off the second *night*:

> I left **the night before last**.

Comment: It is also common to use the day of the week as a reference. For example, if today is Friday, I would say "I left Wednesday night". "The night before last" is usually good, but it can get confusing if you have this conversation very early in the morning/very late at night when "last night" starts to become ambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

`overmorrow` and `ereyesterday` are the two related words that might be of interest, but they are not in (common) use anymore. Source: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/day_after_tomorrow)

As mentioned in snailboat's comment, do not use these words as they are obsolete.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend learners use either of these words, as they're not likely to be understood in most contexts.  (Both words are **obsolete**, as Wiktionary notes.)  They're great words, though!

Comment: Absolutely, but I provided the answer for completeness.

Comment: Has English ever had  words for one day farther than that, I mean "the day after overmorrow" and "the day before ereyesterday".